# Notify object references with some property changed

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, interface, inotifypropertychanged

I need to notify object references with property changed, check the following code:

```
Public Class Symbol
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = Nothing)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Private _Price As Decimal
    Public Property Price() As Decimal
        Get
            Return _Price
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            If Not (value = _Price) Then
                _Price = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged()
            End If

        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

```
Public Class Position
    Public Symbol As Symbol

    Public Sub New(symbol As Symbol)
        Me.Symbol = symbol
    End Sub

    Public Sub PriceChanged()
        Debug.Print($"New Price {Symbol.Price}")
    End Sub

End Class
```

How do I get the PriceChanged to start when *Symbol* price changed?

Comment: Have you had a look at [AddHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement)?

Comment: yes buddy, but first need to implement with [propertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netcore-3.1) if it is possible.

Comment: That's how the `INotifyPropertyChanged` pattern works. You raise the event in the NotifyPropertychanged producer class and have consumer classes that listen for notifications. You declared a public event (`Public Event PropertyChanged`) for this reason.

Comment: You can also use Bindings and a BindingSource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to declare the `Symbol` field `WithEvents`. You can then include that field in a `Handles` clause, just as you do with controls on a form. You can use the navigation bar at the top of the code window to generate the event handler, just as do with controls on a form:

```vb
Public Class Position

    Private WithEvents _symbol As Symbol

    Public Property Symbol As Symbol
        Get
            Return _symbol
        End Get
        Set
            _symbol = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(symbol As Symbol)
        Me.Symbol = symbol
    End Sub

    Public Sub Symbol_PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles _symbol.PropertyChanged
        Debug.Print($"New Price {Symbol.Price}")
    End Sub

End Class
```

I took the liberty of implementing the rest of the class properly too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, already I tried this solution but I'm searched for something instead of handlers if no possible I will go with it, thanks again.

Comment: Why would you not want to do this? You can use `AddHandler` if you prefer but it offers no advantage. If you really want to do it then I can provide an example but if there's no good reason...